# Querying a Table during its Trigger

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

Below I have the code for a trigger:

```html
create or replace trigger "RESPONSES_TABLE_T1"
AFTER
insert or update or delete on "RESPONSES_TABLE"
for each row
begin
DECLARE
    assemblyCount number(3,1);
    numCriteria number(4,1);
    numParts number(4,1);
    numYes number (7,1);
    numNA number (7,1);
    percentComplete number (5,2);

BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(CRITERIA_ID) INTO numCriteria FROM CRITERIA_V6;
    SELECT COUNT(ASSEMBLY_ID) INTO assemblyCount FROM ASSEMBLIES;
    FOR i IN 1..assemblyCount LOOP
        SELECT COUNT(PART_ID) INTO numParts FROM PARTS WHERE ASSEMBLY_ID = i;
        apex_debug.info(p_message => 'Num Parts: ' || TO_CHAR(numParts));
        SELECT COUNT(RESPONSE_ID) INTO numYes FROM RESPONSES_TABLE WHERE ASSEMBLY_ID = i AND RESPONSE = 'Yes';
        apex_debug.info(p_message => 'Num Yes: ' || TO_CHAR(numYes));
        SELECT COUNT(RESPONSE_ID) INTO numNA FROM RESPONSES_TABLE WHERE ASSEMBLY_ID = i AND RESPONSE = 'N/A';
        apex_debug.info(p_message => 'Num N/A: ' || TO_CHAR(numNA));

        percentComplete := numYes / (numCriteria - numNA);
        apex_debug.info(p_message => 'Percent Complete: ' || TO_CHAR(percentComplete));

        UPDATE ASSEMBLIES
            SET COMPLETION = percentComplete
        WHERE ASSEMBLY_ID = i;
    END LOOP;
END;
end;
```

This trigger gives me an ORA-04091 error that I believe is caused by querying `RESPONSE_TABLE` during a trigger on the table itself.  The problem is I need the number of records in these columns and using `COUNT(:new.RESPONSE_ID)` or `COUNT(:old.RESPONSE_ID)` haven't fixed the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at statement level trigger. Your trigger fires for each row and this throws mutating table trigger error. Or check if this can be achieved using a view

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a trigger to update a table ASSEMBLIES, you could consider creating a view that calculates the completion for each assembly record. It will always be up to date and there is no trigger to be maintained.

A trigger is not optimal for this, it will affect performance (lots of code needs to run on every update). Triggers are a tricky thing to maintain as your application matures and becomes more complex.